# How to send Email Payments from system?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

In our system, invoices are made with cronjob before few days (say 10 days) and are emailed to customer from system. Now our client need facility, that from email only, user can click on paypal button and proceed for payment. Can anyone let me know how to do that? I searched on paypal site and they said, you have to generate invoice from their system.

Thank you
Tejas Mehta

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Invoice API's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#invoicing) to send out an invoice from your account.  You can find more on the [Invoice API's here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#invoicing).  There are also some [SDK's](http://paypal.github.io/) and code samples on PayPal's Developer site as well that will help you get started.